# S3 PutObject to CloudFront using presigned URL built for S3 causes error

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

In my server, I build a presigned S3 URL like this:

```
// Initialize a session in us-east-1 that the SDK will use to load
// credentials from the shared credentials file ~/.aws/credentials.
sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
    Region: aws.String("us-east-1")},
)
if err != nil {
    // ...
}

// Create S3 service client.
svc := s3.New(sess)

// Create the S3 PutObject request.
resp, _ := svc.PutObjectRequest(&s3.PutObjectInput{
    Bucket: aws.String("REDACTED"),
    Key:    aws.String(key),
})

// Pre-sign the request to get a URL.
url, err := resp.Presign(20 * time.Second)
if err != nil {
    // ...
}
```

In the browser, I make a `PutObject` call to S3 using the presigned URL, like this (notice that I change the `REDACTED.s3.amazonaws.com` URL to `https://cdn.REDACTED.com`, which is my CloudFront endpoint:

```
http.get(`/get-presigned-url`).subscribe(
    (url: string) =>  {
        const s3Url = 'https://REDACTED.s3.amazonaws.com/';
        const cloudfrontUrl = 'https://cdn.REDACTED.com/';
        http.put(url.replace(s3Url, cloudfrontUrl), file).subscribe(...);
    }
);
```

The browser gives me this error in return, a 400 Bad Request:

> "
>       `InvalidArgument`Only one auth mechanism allowed; only the X-Amz-Algorithm query parameter, Signature
>   query string parameter or the Authorization header should be
>   specifiedAuthorizationAWS
>   REDACTED=REDACTED+REDACTED/REDACTED="

Any ideas what's up?

Comment: Use https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/aws/request/#Request.PresignRequest to get the proper headers that you need to include with the request, then when sending the put request from javascript make sure to use those headers, probably also remove any other headers that may be set by any of the js libs that you use but that are unrelated to the aws s3 put request.

Comment: I get no headers back when using that approach, thus I get the same error.

Comment: I believe you are trying to do something unsupported, but your heavily-redacted error message makes it difficult to pinpoint.  Does the signed URL contain `Signature` or `X-Amz-Signature`?  Also confirm that you are not sending an `Authorization` header yourself.

Comment: I've confirmed that an Authorization header isn't being set. I am doing something to prevent that specifically because it was an issue I dealt with before, so that's not the problem here. Maybe you're right, it's probably unsupported. I don't see why, though, if you can do GET/HEAD/OPTIONS, but you can't do POST/PUT even though you enable all of those methods in the CloudFront behaviors, then something is inconsistent there.

Comment: had the same issue, the problem was that i sand another authorization header along the request accidentally....

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot How does it work for RNFetchblob ?
I'm using : `RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST', url, {Authorization}, RNFetchBlob.wrap(filePath))`
What should I put in place of Authorization ? I only have the signed url from s3